# Getting 400(bad request) when created httpbody by passing dictionary

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, dictionary

Getting 400(bad request) when created httpbody by passing dictionary

```
 var postData = getJSONData(dict: [["keyword": "", "page":0, "size":10, "sortBy":"id", "status": 0]])
        print(postData)
    func getJSONData(dict:[[String:Any]]) -> Data? {
        var jsonData = "{\r\n"
        for singleDict in dict {
            for (key, value) in singleDict {
                if value is String{
                    jsonData.append(" \"\(key)\": \"\(value)\",\r\n")
                }
                else if value is Int{
                      jsonData.append(" \"\(key)\": \(value),\r\n")
                }

            }
        }

        jsonData.append("}")
        print("convert data ---------")
        print(jsonData)
        print("-------------")
        return jsonData.data(using: .utf8)

    }
```

but this is working fine when I use httpbody directly copy from postman code

```
let parameters = "{\r\n  \"keyword\": \"\",\r\n  \"page\": 0,\r\n  \"size\": 10,\r\n  \"sortBy\": \"id\",\r\n  \"status\": 0\r\n}"
print(parameters)
```

Could you please tell what wrong I am doing while converting from dictionary to data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use JSONSerialization.

```
func getJSONData(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> Data? {
    do {
        return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dicitonary, options: .prettyPrinted)
    } catch {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to create a proper request body using JSONSerialization then just try this:-

```
mainStr = """
          {"key1":"\(value1)","key2":"\(value2)","key3":"\(value3)"}
          """
```

Whatever you will insert inside triple quotes will get stringify.

PS.- This is not recommended but you can consider it as a workaround.